# Block some characters from being typed in a text box?

Tags: jquery

I'd like to block users from typing certain characters in a text box (want to only allow [a-z], [A-Z], and underscore). I took this from a previous Q, but if I press the arrow keys (in FF 3.6), I get a js error:

```
"window.event is undefined"
```

this is the original code, what can I change window.event to in this case?:

```
$("#myTextBox").bind("keypress", function(event) { 
    var charCode = (event.which) ? event.which : window.event.keyCode;  
    if (charCode <= 13) { 
        return true; 
    } 
    else { 
        var keyChar = String.fromCharCode(charCode); 
        var re = /[a-zA-Z_]/ 
        return re.test(keyChar); 
    }
});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do just this:

```
$("#myTextBox").bind("keypress", function(event) { 
    var charCode = event.which;
    if (charCode <= 13) return true; 

    var keyChar = String.fromCharCode(charCode); 
    return /[a-zA-Z_]/.test(keyChar); 
});​
```

[jQuery normalizes `event.which` already](http://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/event.js#L468)...and [you can test it here](http://jsfiddle.net/cLaDH/) :)

If it didn't, the fix would just be `event.keyCode`, you want to refer to the `event` passed as the parameter to this function, not a property on `window`.  In this case, if the `if` condition was true, it'd return...so there's no need for an `if`/`else`, you can simplify it like I have above.

Comment: Can we use the Change event?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it'll be right for you, but perhaps you might want to use the [Masked Input Plugin](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/)?

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the window because your event is defined in jQuery ($)